# paypal:how to acknowledge my application for every paypal recurring payment period in soap java

Tags: java, soap, paypal

how my java application ackowledges every billing period transaction

simply for every month how my application knows whether transaction is succeeded or not

.ex:  for every 2nd of month i bill must pay in that day how my application executes without manual checkings

Comment: hi andrew thanks for u intrest, for every billing period can i got respose to that returned url? clearly for first transaction sucess paypal server redirects to redirect url that we given,like that for every billing period recurring payment respose comes to that urlredirect url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Instant Payment Notification](https://www.paypal.com/ipn) to send automatic POST data to a script on your server which can then process that data accordingly.

When a recurring payment takes place you'll get an IPN that shows a payment_status of completed, failed / skipped, or whatever happens with the payment.

Comment: hi andrew thanks for u intrest, for every billing period can  i got respose to that returned url? clearly for first transaction sucess paypal server redirects to redirect url that we given,like that for every billing period recurring payment respose comes to that urlredirect url

Comment: The ReturnURL is separate from IPN, which uses NotifyURL.  You'll want to handle any database updates, email notifications, etc. within IPN because the user is not guaranteed to make it back to your return URL (unless you're using Express Checkout.)